# Find out which entity types are used in a project

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-6

After I finished writing a project (could be a console program or an ASP.NET WebForms app) which, through some class library projects it references, accesses existing databases with maybe hundreds of tables in them using EF6 code first, is there a way/tool to find out which entity types are actually used in the console program/web app?

That information reflects which tables are accessed by the program. I need that information for documentation purpose, and to provide it to database manager so that he can grant access rights my program needs to me.

Comment: Grep for "`DbSet\<(.+?)\>`" in your `.csproj` files - each regex match will be the entity types. Note that if you're using EF with a pre-existing DB then you should be using explicit table-names with the `[Table("Schema.TableName")]`  attribute instead of relying on EF guessing the table-name from entity `class` type-names - fortunately you can grep for `[Table("(.+?)")]` easily-enough too.

Comment: @Dai In `.csproj` files? `.csproj` file doesn't contain `dbset` string (case insensitive) at all. I guess you meant in my derived `DbContext` classes. But this doen't really meet my needs because: 1. Entity types and `DbSet`s (there are hundreds of them) are all declared in class library project(s) shared for serveral console/web projects, and what I have to find out are those actually used in one specific console/web app. 2. Some entity types are referenced just through navigation properties, therefore not declared as `DbSet`s.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in your `.cs` files.

Comment: In that case, without having a project-specific `DbContext` that only has `DbSet<T>` properties for the tables it actually uses then it's actually quite impossible (mathematically, at least) to get a simple listing of tables via static-analysis (thanks to the Halting Problem). There is also the fact that database `FUNCTION`, `VIEW`, and `PROCEDURE` objects can all reference tables themselves without application-code having an idea - so the "best" approach would be to enable XEvents on the server and run your application through common-scenarios and get an (incomplete) list of tables that way.

Comment: @Dai Thank you for trying to help. I was dreaming if there's a tool being able to analyze and "traverse" my codes to find out which entity types/properties are read/written.

Comment: Static-analysis can do that- but if the codebase has a `DbContext` with hundreds of tables, as you say, then static-analysis can only give you those you hundreds of tables and can't tell you what is _actually_ used when your program runs.